# iPhone SDK - How to read on text files

Tags: iphone, image, text, plist, coordinates

I want to store some coordinates on a text files that correspond to an image array i will call out on my apps. Is it possible to write it in a notepad and save it as a .txt and be able to read in xcode the coordinates written inside or do i have to use plist format for that?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to read the text file just fine, but writing a plist is trivial and probably will make the reading easier. You can also directly write a header file with the coordinates:

```
// Coords.h
int coordinates[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Depends on what exactly you need that for.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick reply. Just wondering also is it advisable also to just make another class just for the coordinates? Im probably storing a lot of coordinates coz im gonna use it later to compare to user touches coord.

Comment: The header approach is a bit of a hack. Somebody might consider it overkill, but I’d probably wrap the coordinates into a class that would read the data from a plist. Then you can write a sample coordinate plist and check the loading routine using a unit test. Sounds complicated, but it should only take a while.